# How can I play an rtmp video on ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, rtmp

I need to reproduce an rtmp link in my application in ionic framework v3.
I already try using video.js and it does not work or at least not for me.
Also using the api that ionic provides, but does not bring much documentation and does not work either.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer will be you can not play RTMP streams in ionic because ionic is Webview based and RTMP is not supported natively by Webview.

Solution for you problem will be to convert RTMP stream to other format server side or create a native application which can decode RTMP streams.